# Rust convert Option<T> to Option<U>

Tags: rust

How can I convert an `Option` of one type into an `Option` of another type in Rust?

I managed to sketch this out in the Rust playground, but this is a lot of boilerplate code to do what seems like a common operation.

In this example, I have a data transfer object which contains an `Option::<String>`, which I wish to convert to an `Option::<Price>` type, where `Price` is some internal struct type.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct DTO {
    pub dto_data: Option::<String>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Price {
    pub internal_price: i64,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct InternalType {
    pub internal_data: Option::<Price>,
}

fn main() {

    let dto = DTO {
        dto_data: Some(String::from("10")),
    };
    
    println!("{:?}", dto);
    
    let mut option_price: Option<Price> = None;
    
    if let Some(price_exists) = dto.dto_data {
        option_price = Some(Price {
            internal_price: price_exists.parse().unwrap()
        });
    }
    
    let internal_type = InternalType {
        internal_data: option_price,
    };

    println!("{:?}", internal_type);
    
}
```

Actually, I am fairly sure there is a bug in my code, because the Rust playground produces warnings about dead code. Still, the output seems ok.

That point aside, does Rust provide a simpler way to do this? Perhaps with some kind of helper function or trait?

---

## Output:

### Compiler:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
warning: field `internal_price` is never read
 --> src/main.rs:9:9
  |
8 | struct Price {
  |        ----- field in this struct
9 |     pub internal_price: i64,
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `Price` has a derived impl for the trait `Debug`, but this is intentionally ignored during dead code analysis
  = note: `#[warn(dead_code)]` on by default

warning: field `internal_data` is never read
  --> src/main.rs:14:9
   |
13 | struct InternalType {
   |        ------------ field in this struct
14 |     pub internal_data: Option::<Price>,
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: `InternalType` has a derived impl for the trait `Debug`, but this is intentionally ignored during dead code analysis

warning: `playground` (bin "playground") generated 2 warnings
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.80s
     Running `target/debug/playground`
```

### Standard Output:

```
DTO { dto_data: Some("10") }
InternalType { internal_data: Some(Price { internal_price: 10 }) }
```

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map ?

Comment: The dead code analysis is right, you never *use* the value in the fields of the structs, you just assign them. However, it's not an issue: Rust just warns you about that because, in production code, it's usually a bit odd to never use a field without having properly informed Rust that you didn't intend to use it (yet).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably asking for [`Option::map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map):

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct DTO {
    pub dto_data: Option<String>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Price {
    pub internal_price: i64,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct InternalType {
    pub internal_data: Option<Price>,
}

fn main() {
    let dto = DTO {
        dto_data: Some(String::from("10")),
    };

    println!("{:?}", dto);

    let internal_type = InternalType {
        internal_data: dto.dto_data.map(|p| Price {
            internal_price: p.parse().unwrap(),
        }),
    };

    println!("{:?}", internal_type);
}
```

```
DTO { dto_data: Some("10") }
InternalType { internal_data: Some(Price { internal_price: 10 }) }
```

Comment: For this case `and_then` might fit better to avoid unwrap unless op wants to handle parsing error. What I meant is : `dto_data.and_then(|p| { p.parse().map(|internal_price| Price { internal_price }).ok()})`;

Comment: Sure. I just tried to stay as true to OPs original code as possible. If/how he wants to handle the errors is out of scope for this question imo. I tried not to change behavior of the code, and with `and_then` all in a sudden `None` and "parse error" would behave identical, while in OPs code the latter would panic.